# _iteratorError undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The following code takes the content of a file, replace some characters, and outputs the result:

**test.txt:**

```
# Title

## Title 2

Paragraph
```

**index.js:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('babel/polyfill')

'use strict'

var fs = require('fs')
  , filename = process.argv[2]

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME')
  process.exit(1)
}

function massReplace(text, replacementArray) {
  let results = text
  for (let [regex, replacement] of replacementArray) {
    results = results.replace(regex, replacement)
  }
  return results
}

function transformHeadings(text, orig) {
  return massReplace(text,
     [/^## (.*)/gm,     '<h2>$1</h2>'],
     [/^# (.*)/gm,      '<h1>$1</h1>'] ]
  )
}

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err

  data = data.split(/\n\n/gm)
  var tree = data.slice()

  console.log(transformHeadings(data, tree))
})
```

I get this error:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n$ babel-node index4.js test.txt
/home/alex/node/m2n/index4.js:41
        throw _iteratorError;
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at massReplace (/home/alex/node/m2n/index4.js:17:4)
    at transformHeadings (/home/alex/node/m2n/index4.js:30:2)
    at /home/alex/node/m2n/index4.js:39:3
    at fs.js:336:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

No idea what the problem is, nor what `throw _iteratorError` means.

I'm using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to parse the ES6 code.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

This is the compiled function. But I still can't see the problem:

```
function massReplace(text, replacementArray) {
  var results = text;
  var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
  var _didIteratorError = false;
  var _iteratorError = undefined;

  try {
    for (var _iterator = replacementArray[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
      var _step$value = _slicedToArray(_step.value, 2);

      var regex = _step$value[0];
      var replacement = _step$value[1];

      results = results.replace(regex, replacement);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
  } finally {
    try {
      if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator["return"]) {
        _iterator["return"]();
      }
    } finally {
      if (_didIteratorError) {
        throw _iteratorError;
      }
    }
  }

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
require ('babel/polyfill');
```

For certain features, Babel uses a small support library. For more info, see https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ and http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/

Hope that helps!

Edit:

So I noticed that actually `transformHeadings` isn't being passed the right parameters. `text` should be a string, not an array. You'll want to iterate over `data` a line at a time instead of passing in the entire array.

The reason you get this error is because an array doesn't have a `replace` method, so an exception is raised. I'm not clear why Babel isn't properly re-raising the error here, though, which definitely adds to the confusion.

Comment: thanks for the help but I'm still getting the same problem. Please see my answer. I updated it and added the compiled ES5 code.

Comment: I've updated the answer; tl;dr: massReplace and transformHeadings is expecting a string, not an array.